# .NET AWS SDK - Region missing in ARN for multi region access point

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-s3-access-points

I am trying to write a simple .NET console app that puts an object into an AWS S3 bucket via a multi region access point.  I get the following error: `Amazon.Runtime.AmazonClientException: AWS region is missing in access point ARN`

My arn format for multi region access points came from the documentation [Making requests using a Multi-Region Access Point](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/MultiRegionAccessPointRequests.html).

I also set the ENV variable `AWS_S3_DISABLE_MULTIREGION_ACCESS_POINTS=false`. Even though this is the default, I did explicitly set it to be sure the SDK should not be excluding mrap [Amazon S3 Multi-Region Access Points](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/feature-s3-mrap.html).

I'm using the v3.x AWS .NET SDK, and reasonably confident that IAM and S3 policies are correct because I can put objects via the CLI no problem.  I'm sure I'm missing something totally obvious, but any help is appreciated.

```
using Amazon;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;

string bucketName = "arn:aws:s3::123456789012:accesspoint/randomstring.mrap";
string keyName = "some/path/test.txt";

AmazonS3Client client;
AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();

config.UseArnRegion = false;
config.RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USWest2;

client = new AmazonS3Client(config);

PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest()
{
    ContentBody = "this is a test",
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Key = keyName
};

client.PutObjectAsync(request).Wait();
```

Comment: Aha - try `arn:aws:s3::123456789012:accesspoint:randomstring.mrap`

Comment: Unfortunately that format returns the same error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this - I've just been able to insert an object using an MRAP endpoint using your exact code. Are you sure you don't have a random character mistakenly inserted somewhere in your ARN? But I am 100% sure that the code above works.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I really appreciate you looking into this.  I'm confident my arn is correct.  Could you please share the exact version of AWS & .NET SDKs you used?  If that code is working for you, that's the only thing left I can come up with.

Comment: No worries! .NET 6.0.300, AWSSDK.S3 3.7.9.14 (latest) &  AWSSDK.Extensions.CrtIntegration 3.7.1.4

Comment: The above code does NOT work for me with AWSSDK.S3 3.7.101.1 (latest) & AWSSDK.Extensions.CrtIntegration 3.7.1.4 & .NET 6.0.100..... tried many alternatives and no luck. I get a different error  though: Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: We encountered an internal error. Please try again. (no matter how many times I try)